# Normal Subgroups of $UT_n(q)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, normal-subgroups

What is known about normal subgroups of $UT_n(q)$, the group of upper triangular matrices with entries in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and ones on the diagonal? Is there an interpretation of the lattice of its normal subgroups or of some sublattices of the lattice of normal subgroups?

Comment: your groups is typically denoted by $UT_n(q)$. $U_n(q)$ is used for unitary groups.

Comment: It has a huge number of normal subgroups. I think you need to make your question more focused.

Comment: Is there an interpretation of the lattice of normal subgroups or of some sublattices of the lattice of normal subgroups?